# Get AutoCAD.Application Instance

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autodesk

I want to get an AutoCAD.Application instance.
However, an error occurs when GetActiveObject() is executed during the AutoCAD loading screen.
If I set a breakpoint and call GetActiveObject() after loading is finished, the instance is got well.
Is there an event or other method in .Net to use when the loading window ends?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AcadApplication objAcad = default(AcadApplication);
    const string strProgId = "AutoCAD.Application.24.1";

    Process myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2022\" + "acad.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    myProcess.Start();
    
    try
    {
        objAcad = Marshal.GetActiveObject(strProgId) as AcadApplication;
        if (objAcad is null)
            throw new Exception("obj is null");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) // An error occurs if no instance is running
    {
        Type acType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(strProgId);

        objAcad = (AcadApplication)Activator.CreateInstance(acType, true);
    }

    objAcad.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify why you need to do all this manually instead of just calling `new AcadApplication()` (if you can guarantee exact versoin of AutoCAD installed) or `ActivatorCreateInstance(acType)` (version independent)? Both approaches should connect to running AutoCAD instance or run new one if none running.

Comment: I don't use AcadApplication() because I have to run multiple versions.

I tried using Activator.CreateInstance(acType) and I got the following COMException.

Comment: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done this way:

```
  AcadApplication acadApp = null;
  const string progId = "AutoCAD.Application.24.1";
 
  // Try to get a running instance of AutoCAD
  try
  {
      acadApp = (AcadApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject(progId);
  }
  catch // An error occurs if no instance is running
  {
      try
      {
          // Try to create a new instance of AutoCAD
          acadApp = (AcadApplication)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId), true);
      }
      catch
      {
          // If an instance of AutoCAD is not created then message and exit
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
              "Instance of 'AutoCAD.Application' could not be created.");
 
          return;
      }
  }
```